# How to set up a 3d FEM solver with PETSc Scalable Nonlinear Equations Solvers?

Tags: c, 3d, petsc

In 3.3 they had a [grate news](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/changes/33.html) - an example of FEM solving using only PETCs SNES on GPU. I am new to PETSc and have a problem - I need to create a sphere in 3d space and apply forces to it... so I need a 3d FEM (if possible on GPU, no MPI required for my case). Yet when I [see the simple example](https://github.com/petsc/petsc/blob/master/src/snes/examples/tutorials/ex52.c) they provide I get a bit scarry:

```
static const char help[] = "Testbed for FEM operations on the GPU.\n\n";

#include<petscdmplex.h>
#include<petscsnes.h>

#define NUM_FIELDS 1
PetscInt spatialDim = 0;

typedef enum {LAPLACIAN = 0, ELASTICITY} OpType;

typedef struct {
  PetscFEM      fem;               /* REQUIRED to use DMPlexComputeResidualFEM() */
  DM            dm;                /* The solution DM */
  PetscInt      debug;             /* The debugging level */
  PetscMPIInt   rank;              /* The process rank */
  PetscMPIInt   numProcs;          /* The number of processes */
  PetscInt      dim;               /* The topological mesh dimension */
  PetscBool     interpolate;       /* Generate intermediate mesh elements */
  PetscReal     refinementLimit;   /* The largest allowable cell volume */
  PetscBool     refinementUniform; /* Uniformly refine the mesh */
  PetscInt      refinementRounds;  /* The number of uniform refinements */
  char          partitioner[2048]; /* The graph partitioner */
  PetscBool     computeFunction;   /* The flag for computing a residual */
  PetscBool     computeJacobian;   /* The flag for computing a Jacobian */
  PetscBool     gpu;               /* The flag for GPU integration */
  OpType        op;                /* The type of PDE operator (should use FFC/Ignition here) */
  PetscBool     showResidual, showJacobian;
  PetscLogEvent createMeshEvent, residualEvent, residualBatchEvent, jacobianEvent, jacobianBatchEvent, integrateBatchCPUEvent, integrateBatchGPUEvent, integrateGPUOnlyEvent;
  /* Element definition */
  PetscFE       fe[NUM_FIELDS];
  PetscFE       feAux[1];
  void (*f0Funcs[NUM_FIELDS])(const PetscScalar u[], const PetscScalar gradU[], const PetscScalar a[], const PetscScalar gradA[], const PetscReal x[], PetscScalar f0[]);
  void (*f1Funcs[NUM_FIELDS])(const PetscScalar u[], const PetscScalar gradU[], const PetscScalar a[], const PetscScalar gradA[], const PetscReal x[], PetscScalar f1[]);
  void (*g0Funcs[NUM_FIELDS*NUM_FIELDS])(const PetscScalar u[], const PetscScalar gradU[], const PetscScalar a[], const PetscScalar gradA[], const PetscReal x[], PetscScalar g0[]);
  void (*g1Funcs[NUM_FIELDS*NUM_FIELDS])(const PetscScalar u[], const PetscScalar gradU[], const PetscScalar a[], const PetscScalar gradA[], const PetscReal x[], PetscScalar g1[]);
  void (*g2Funcs[NUM_FIELDS*NUM_FIELDS])(const PetscScalar u[], const PetscScalar gradU[], const PetscScalar a[], const PetscScalar gradA[], const PetscReal x[], PetscScalar g2[]);
  void (*g3Funcs[NUM_FIELDS*NUM_FIELDS])(const PetscScalar u[], const PetscScalar gradU[], const PetscScalar a[], const PetscScalar gradA[], const PetscReal x[], PetscScalar g3[]);
  void (**exactFuncs)(const PetscReal x[], PetscScalar *u, void *ctx);
} AppCtx;

void quadratic_2d(const PetscReal x[], PetscScalar u[], void *ctx)
{
  u[0] = x[0]*x[0] + x[1]*x[1];
};

void quadratic_2d_elas(const PetscReal x[], PetscScalar u[], void *ctx)
{
  u[0] = x[0]*x[0] + x[1]*x[1];
  u[1] = x[0]*x[0] + x[1]*x[1];
};

void f0_lap(const PetscScalar u[], const PetscScalar gradU[], const PetscScalar a[], const PetscScalar gradA[], const PetscReal x[], PetscScalar f0[])
{
  f0[0] = 4.0;
}

/* gradU[comp*dim+d] = {u_x, u_y} or {u_x, u_y, u_z} */
void f1_lap(const PetscScalar u[], const PetscScalar gradU[], const PetscScalar a[], const PetscScalar gradA[], const PetscReal x[], PetscScalar f1[])
{
  PetscInt d;
  for (d = 0; d < spatialDim; ++d) {f1[d] = a[0]*gradU[d];}
}

/* < \nabla v, \nabla u + {\nabla u}^T >
   This just gives \nabla u, give the perdiagonal for the transpose */
void g3_lap(const PetscScalar u[], const PetscScalar gradU[], const PetscScalar a[], const PetscScalar gradA[], const PetscReal x[], PetscScalar g3[])
{
  PetscInt d;
  for (d = 0; d < spatialDim; ++d) {g3[d*spatialDim+d] = 1.0;}
}

void f0_elas(const PetscScalar u[], const PetscScalar gradU[], const PetscScalar a[], const PetscScalar gradA[], const PetscReal x[], PetscScalar f0[])
{
  const PetscInt Ncomp = spatialDim;
  PetscInt       comp;

  for (comp = 0; comp < Ncomp; ++comp) f0[comp] = 3.0;
}

/* gradU[comp*dim+d] = {u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y} or {u_x, u_y, u_z, v_x, v_y, v_z, w_x, w_y, w_z}
   u[Ncomp]          = {p} */
void f1_elas(const PetscScalar u[], const PetscScalar gradU[], const PetscScalar a[], const PetscScalar gradA[], const PetscReal x[], PetscScalar f1[])
{
  const PetscInt dim   = spatialDim;
  const PetscInt Ncomp = spatialDim;
  PetscInt       comp, d;

  for (comp = 0; comp < Ncomp; ++comp) {
    for (d = 0; d < dim; ++d) {
      f1[comp*dim+d] = 0.5*(gradU[comp*dim+d] + gradU[d*dim+comp]);
    }
    f1[comp*dim+comp] -= u[Ncomp];
  }
}

/* < \nabla v, \nabla u + {\nabla u}^T >
   This just gives \nabla u, give the perdiagonal for the transpose */
void g3_elas(const PetscScalar u[], const PetscScalar gradU[], const PetscScalar a[], const PetscScalar gradA[], const PetscReal x[], PetscScalar g3[])
{
  const PetscInt dim   = spatialDim;
  const PetscInt Ncomp = spatialDim;
  PetscInt       compI, d;

  for (compI = 0; compI < Ncomp; ++compI) {
    for (d = 0; d < dim; ++d) {
      g3[((compI*Ncomp+compI)*dim+d)*dim+d] = 1.0;
    }
  }
}

#undef __FUNCT__
#define __FUNCT__ "ProcessOptions"
PetscErrorCode ProcessOptions(MPI_Comm comm, AppCtx *options)
{
  const char     *opTypes[2] = {"laplacian", "elasticity"};
  PetscInt       op;
  PetscErrorCode ierr;

  PetscFunctionBeginUser;
  options->debug             = 0;
  options->dim               = 2;
  options->interpolate       = PETSC_FALSE;
  options->refinementLimit   = 0.0;
  options->refinementUniform = PETSC_FALSE;
  options->refinementRounds  = 1;
  options->computeFunction   = PETSC_FALSE;
  options->computeJacobian   = PETSC_FALSE;
  options->gpu               = PETSC_FALSE;
  options->op                = LAPLACIAN;
  options->showResidual      = PETSC_TRUE;
  options->showJacobian      = PETSC_TRUE;

  ierr = MPI_Comm_size(comm, &options->numProcs);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &options->rank);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscOptionsBegin(comm, "", "Bratu Problem Options", "DMPLEX");CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscOptionsInt("-debug", "The debugging level", "ex52.c", options->debug, &options->debug, NULL);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscOptionsInt("-dim", "The topological mesh dimension", "ex52.c", options->dim, &options->dim, NULL);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  spatialDim = options->dim;
  ierr = PetscOptionsBool("-interpolate", "Generate intermediate mesh elements", "ex52.c", options->interpolate, &options->interpolate, NULL);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscOptionsReal("-refinement_limit", "The largest allowable cell volume", "ex52.c", options->refinementLimit, &options->refinementLimit, NULL);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscOptionsBool("-refinement_uniform", "Uniformly refine the mesh", "ex52.c", options->refinementUniform, &options->refinementUniform, NULL);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscOptionsInt("-refinement_rounds", "The number of uniform refinements", "ex52.c", options->refinementRounds, &options->refinementRounds, NULL);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscStrcpy(options->partitioner, "chaco");CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscOptionsString("-partitioner", "The graph partitioner", "ex52.c", options->partitioner, options->partitioner, 2048, NULL);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscOptionsBool("-compute_function", "Compute the residual", "ex52.c", options->computeFunction, &options->computeFunction, NULL);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscOptionsBool("-compute_jacobian", "Compute the Jacobian", "ex52.c", options->computeJacobian, &options->computeJacobian, NULL);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscOptionsBool("-gpu", "Use the GPU for integration method", "ex52.c", options->gpu, &options->gpu, NULL);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  op = options->op;
  ierr = PetscOptionsEList("-op_type","Type of PDE operator","ex52.c",opTypes,2,opTypes[options->op],&op,NULL);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  options->op = (OpType) op;

  ierr = PetscOptionsBool("-show_residual", "Output the residual for verification", "ex52.c", options->showResidual, &options->showResidual, NULL);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscOptionsBool("-show_jacobian", "Output the Jacobian for verification", "ex52.c", options->showJacobian, &options->showJacobian, NULL);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscOptionsEnd();

  ierr = PetscLogEventRegister("CreateMesh",    DM_CLASSID,   &options->createMeshEvent);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscLogEventRegister("Residual",      SNES_CLASSID, &options->residualEvent);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscLogEventRegister("ResidualBatch", SNES_CLASSID, &options->residualBatchEvent);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscLogEventRegister("Jacobian",      SNES_CLASSID, &options->jacobianEvent);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscLogEventRegister("JacobianBatch", SNES_CLASSID, &options->jacobianBatchEvent);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscLogEventRegister("IntegBatchCPU", SNES_CLASSID, &options->integrateBatchCPUEvent);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscLogEventRegister("IntegBatchGPU", SNES_CLASSID, &options->integrateBatchGPUEvent);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscLogEventRegister("IntegGPUOnly",  SNES_CLASSID, &options->integrateGPUOnlyEvent);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  PetscFunctionReturn(0);
};

#undef __FUNCT__
#define __FUNCT__ "CreateMesh"
PetscErrorCode CreateMesh(MPI_Comm comm, AppCtx *user, DM *dm)
{
  PetscInt       dim               = user->dim;
  PetscBool      interpolate       = user->interpolate;
  PetscReal      refinementLimit   = user->refinementLimit;
  PetscBool      refinementUniform = user->refinementUniform;
  PetscInt       refinementRounds  = user->refinementRounds;
  const char     *partitioner      = user->partitioner;
  PetscErrorCode ierr;

  PetscFunctionBeginUser;
  ierr = PetscLogEventBegin(user->createMeshEvent,0,0,0,0);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = DMPlexCreateBoxMesh(comm, dim, interpolate, dm);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  {
    DM refinedMesh     = NULL;
    DM distributedMesh = NULL;

    /* Refine mesh using a volume constraint */
    ierr = DMPlexSetRefinementLimit(*dm, refinementLimit);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = DMRefine(*dm, comm, &refinedMesh);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    if (refinedMesh) {
      ierr = DMDestroy(dm);CHKERRQ(ierr);
      *dm  = refinedMesh;
    }
    /* Distribute mesh over processes */
    ierr = DMPlexDistribute(*dm, partitioner, 0, NULL, &distributedMesh);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    if (distributedMesh) {
      ierr = DMDestroy(dm);CHKERRQ(ierr);
      *dm  = distributedMesh;
    }
    /* Use regular refinement in parallel */
    if (refinementUniform) {
      PetscInt r;

      ierr = DMPlexSetRefinementUniform(*dm, refinementUniform);CHKERRQ(ierr);
      for (r = 0; r < refinementRounds; ++r) {
        ierr = DMRefine(*dm, comm, &refinedMesh);CHKERRQ(ierr);
        if (refinedMesh) {
          ierr = DMDestroy(dm);CHKERRQ(ierr);
          *dm  = refinedMesh;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ierr = PetscObjectSetName((PetscObject) *dm, "Mesh");CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = DMSetFromOptions(*dm);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscLogEventEnd(user->createMeshEvent,0,0,0,0);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  user->dm = *dm;
  PetscFunctionReturn(0);
}

#undef __FUNCT__
#define __FUNCT__ "SetupElement"
PetscErrorCode SetupElement(DM dm, AppCtx *user)
{
  const PetscInt  dim = user->dim;
  PetscFE         fem;
  PetscQuadrature q;
  DM              K;
  PetscSpace      P;
  PetscDualSpace  Q;
  PetscInt        order;
  PetscErrorCode  ierr;

  PetscFunctionBegin;
  /* Create space */
  ierr = PetscSpaceCreate(PetscObjectComm((PetscObject) dm), &P);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscSpaceSetFromOptions(P);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscSpacePolynomialSetNumVariables(P, dim);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscSpaceSetUp(P);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscSpaceGetOrder(P, &order);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  /* Create dual space */
  ierr = PetscDualSpaceCreate(PetscObjectComm((PetscObject) dm), &Q);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscDualSpaceCreateReferenceCell(Q, dim, PETSC_TRUE, &K);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscDualSpaceSetDM(Q, K);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = DMDestroy(&K);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscDualSpaceSetOrder(Q, order);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscDualSpaceSetFromOptions(Q);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscDualSpaceSetUp(Q);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  /* Create element */
  ierr = PetscFECreate(PetscObjectComm((PetscObject) dm), &fem);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscFESetFromOptions(fem);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscFESetBasisSpace(fem, P);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscFESetDualSpace(fem, Q);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscFESetNumComponents(fem, 1);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscFESetUp(fem);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscSpaceDestroy(&P);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscDualSpaceDestroy(&Q);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  /* Create quadrature */
  ierr = PetscDTGaussJacobiQuadrature(dim, order, -1.0, 1.0, &q);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscFESetQuadrature(fem, q);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscQuadratureDestroy(&q);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  user->fe[0] = fem;
  user->fem.fe = user->fe;
  PetscFunctionReturn(0);
}

#undef __FUNCT__
#define __FUNCT__ "SetupMaterialElement"
PetscErrorCode SetupMaterialElement(DM dm, AppCtx *user)
{
  const PetscInt  dim = user->dim;
  const char     *prefix = "mat_";
  PetscFE         fem;
  PetscQuadrature q;
  DM              K;
  PetscSpace      P;
  PetscDualSpace  Q;
  PetscInt        order;
  PetscErrorCode  ierr;

  PetscFunctionBegin;
  /* Create space */
  ierr = PetscSpaceCreate(PetscObjectComm((PetscObject) dm), &P);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscObjectSetOptionsPrefix((PetscObject) P, prefix);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscSpaceSetFromOptions(P);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscSpacePolynomialSetNumVariables(P, dim);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscSpaceSetUp(P);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscSpaceGetOrder(P, &order);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  /* Create dual space */
  ierr = PetscDualSpaceCreate(PetscObjectComm((PetscObject) dm), &Q);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscObjectSetOptionsPrefix((PetscObject) Q, prefix);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscDualSpaceCreateReferenceCell(Q, dim, PETSC_TRUE, &K);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscDualSpaceSetDM(Q, K);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = DMDestroy(&K);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscDualSpaceSetOrder(Q, order);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscDualSpaceSetFromOptions(Q);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscDualSpaceSetUp(Q);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  /* Create element */
  ierr = PetscFECreate(PetscObjectComm((PetscObject) dm), &fem);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscObjectSetOptionsPrefix((PetscObject) fem, prefix);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscFESetFromOptions(fem);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscFESetBasisSpace(fem, P);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscFESetDualSpace(fem, Q);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscFESetNumComponents(fem, 1);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscSpaceDestroy(&P);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscDualSpaceDestroy(&Q);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  /* Create quadrature */
  ierr = PetscDTGaussJacobiQuadrature(dim, PetscMax(order, 1), -1.0, 1.0, &q);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscFESetQuadrature(fem, q);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  user->feAux[0]  = fem;
  user->fem.feAux = user->feAux;
  PetscFunctionReturn(0);
}

#undef __FUNCT__
#define __FUNCT__ "DestroyElement"
PetscErrorCode DestroyElement(AppCtx *user)
{
  PetscErrorCode ierr;

  PetscFunctionBeginUser;
  ierr = PetscFEDestroy(&user->fe[0]);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscFEDestroy(&user->feAux[0]);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  PetscFunctionReturn(0);
}

#undef __FUNCT__
#define __FUNCT__ "SetupSection"
PetscErrorCode SetupSection(DM dm, AppCtx *user)
{
  PetscSection    section;
  PetscInt        dim   = user->dim;
  PetscInt        numBC = 0;
  PetscInt        numComp[1];
  const PetscInt *numDof;
  PetscErrorCode  ierr;

  PetscFunctionBeginUser;
  ierr = PetscFEGetNumComponents(user->fe[0], &numComp[0]);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscFEGetNumDof(user->fe[0], &numDof);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = DMPlexCreateSection(dm, dim, 1, numComp, numDof, numBC, NULL, NULL, NULL, &section);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = DMSetDefaultSection(dm, section);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscSectionDestroy(&section);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  PetscFunctionReturn(0);
}

#undef __FUNCT__
#define __FUNCT__ "SetupMaterial"
PetscErrorCode SetupMaterial(DM dm, DM dmAux, AppCtx *user)
{
  Vec            epsilon;
  PetscErrorCode ierr;

  PetscFunctionBegin;
  ierr = DMCreateLocalVector(dmAux, &epsilon);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = VecSet(epsilon, 1.0);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscObjectCompose((PetscObject) dm, "A", (PetscObject) epsilon);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = VecDestroy(&epsilon);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  PetscFunctionReturn(0);
}

#undef __FUNCT__
#define __FUNCT__ "main"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  DM             dm, dmAux;
  SNES           snes;
  AppCtx         user;
  PetscInt       numComp;
  PetscErrorCode ierr;

  ierr = PetscInitialize(&argc, &argv, NULL, help);CHKERRQ(ierr);
#if !defined(PETSC_HAVE_CUDA) && !defined(PETSC_HAVE_OPENCL)
  SETERRQ(PETSC_COMM_WORLD, PETSC_ERR_SUP, "This example requires CUDA or OpenCL support.");
#endif
  ierr = ProcessOptions(PETSC_COMM_WORLD, &user);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = SNESCreate(PETSC_COMM_WORLD, &snes);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = CreateMesh(PETSC_COMM_WORLD, &user, &dm);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = SNESSetDM(snes, dm);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  ierr = SetupElement(user.dm, &user);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = DMClone(user.dm, &dmAux);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscObjectCompose((PetscObject) dm, "dmAux", (PetscObject) dmAux);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = SetupMaterialElement(dmAux, &user);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscFEGetNumComponents(user.fe[0], &numComp);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscMalloc(numComp * sizeof(void (*)(const PetscReal[], PetscScalar *, void *)), &user.exactFuncs);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  switch (user.op) {
  case LAPLACIAN:
    user.f0Funcs[0]    = f0_lap;
    user.f1Funcs[0]    = f1_lap;
    user.g0Funcs[0]    = NULL;
    user.g1Funcs[0]    = NULL;
    user.g2Funcs[0]    = NULL;
    user.g3Funcs[0]    = g3_lap;
    user.exactFuncs[0] = quadratic_2d;
    break;
  case ELASTICITY:
    user.f0Funcs[0]    = f0_elas;
    user.f1Funcs[0]    = f1_elas;
    user.g0Funcs[0]    = NULL;
    user.g1Funcs[0]    = NULL;
    user.g2Funcs[0]    = NULL;
    user.g3Funcs[0]    = g3_elas;
    user.exactFuncs[0] = quadratic_2d_elas;
    break;
  default:
    SETERRQ1(PETSC_COMM_WORLD, PETSC_ERR_ARG_OUTOFRANGE, "Invalid PDE operator %d", user.op);
  }
  user.fem.f0Funcs = user.f0Funcs;
  user.fem.f1Funcs = user.f1Funcs;
  user.fem.g0Funcs = user.g0Funcs;
  user.fem.g1Funcs = user.g1Funcs;
  user.fem.g2Funcs = user.g2Funcs;
  user.fem.g3Funcs = user.g3Funcs;
  user.fem.bcFuncs = user.exactFuncs;
  user.fem.bcCtxs  = NULL;
  ierr = SetupSection(dm, &user);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = SetupSection(dmAux, &user);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = SetupMaterial(dm, dmAux, &user);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  ierr = DMSNESSetFunctionLocal(dm,  (PetscErrorCode (*)(DM,Vec,Vec,void*))DMPlexComputeResidualFEM,&user);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = DMSNESSetJacobianLocal(dm,  (PetscErrorCode (*)(DM,Vec,Mat,Mat,void*))DMPlexComputeJacobianFEM,&user);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  if (user.computeFunction) {
    Vec X, F;

    ierr = DMGetGlobalVector(dm, &X);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = DMGetGlobalVector(dm, &F);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = DMPlexProjectFunction(dm, user.fe, user.exactFuncs, NULL, INSERT_VALUES, X);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = SNESComputeFunction(snes, X, F);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = DMRestoreGlobalVector(dm, &X);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = DMRestoreGlobalVector(dm, &F);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  }
  if (user.computeJacobian) {
    Vec          X;
    Mat          J;

    ierr = DMGetGlobalVector(dm, &X);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = DMSetMatType(dm,MATAIJ);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = DMCreateMatrix(dm, &J);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = SNESComputeJacobian(snes, X, J, J);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = MatDestroy(&J);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = DMRestoreGlobalVector(dm, &X);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  }
  ierr = PetscFree(user.exactFuncs);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = DestroyElement(&user);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = DMDestroy(&dmAux);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = DMDestroy(&dm);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = SNESDestroy(&snes);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscFinalize();
  return 0;
}
```

It is clean and readable C like code...

Yet reading it makes my head ake because coming from bullet phisix\gamedev backgrownd I do not see 3 main things: where dimensions are set, a mesh is created, and forces apply?

So can any one please explain how to set up a 3d FEM solver with PETSc SNES (hilighting how to setup dimensions, feed a mesh, apply forces and interprite the result)?

Comment: BTW they have `PetscFEM` used in sample yet in `petscdmplex` nor in `petscsnes` I can not find it...(

Comment: Please do not tag spam, this is a C question and should not be tagged C++

Answer (score 3):

I do not have experience with these libraries, but here is at least a start (not yet a complete answer).  One thing I see that is very puzzling here is that there does not appear to be a loop in the main program.  Don't feel bad, the lack of comments, coding style and online documentation make this very difficult to figure out.

It appears at least the mesh is created in the function, called from here (in main):

```
ierr = CreateMesh(PETSC_COMM_WORLD, &user, &dm);CHKERRQ(ierr);
```

That function is defined further up in the code here:

```
PetscErrorCode CreateMesh(MPI_Comm comm, AppCtx *user, DM *dm)
{
  PetscInt       dim               = user->dim;
  PetscBool      interpolate       = user->interpolate;
  PetscReal      refinementLimit   = user->refinementLimit;
  PetscBool      refinementUniform = user->refinementUniform;
  PetscInt       refinementRounds  = user->refinementRounds;
  const char     *partitioner      = user->partitioner;
  PetscErrorCode ierr;

  PetscFunctionBeginUser;
  ierr = PetscLogEventBegin(user->createMeshEvent,0,0,0,0);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = DMPlexCreateBoxMesh(comm, dim, interpolate, dm);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  {
    DM refinedMesh     = NULL;
    DM distributedMesh = NULL;

    /* Refine mesh using a volume constraint */
    ierr = DMPlexSetRefinementLimit(*dm, refinementLimit);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    ierr = DMRefine(*dm, comm, &refinedMesh);CHKERRQ(ierr);
   if (refinedMesh) {
      ierr = DMDestroy(dm);CHKERRQ(ierr);
      *dm  = refinedMesh;
    }
    /* Distribute mesh over processes */
    ierr = DMPlexDistribute(*dm, partitioner, 0, NULL, &distributedMesh);CHKERRQ(ierr);
    if (distributedMesh) {
      ierr = DMDestroy(dm);CHKERRQ(ierr);
      *dm  = distributedMesh;
    }
    /* Use regular refinement in parallel */
    if (refinementUniform) {
      PetscInt r;

      ierr = DMPlexSetRefinementUniform(*dm, refinementUniform);CHKERRQ(ierr);
      for (r = 0; r < refinementRounds; ++r) {
        ierr = DMRefine(*dm, comm, &refinedMesh);CHKERRQ(ierr);
        if (refinedMesh) {
          ierr = DMDestroy(dm);CHKERRQ(ierr);
          *dm  = refinedMesh;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ierr = PetscObjectSetName((PetscObject) *dm, "Mesh");CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = DMSetFromOptions(*dm);CHKERRQ(ierr);
  ierr = PetscLogEventEnd(user->createMeshEvent,0,0,0,0);CHKERRQ(ierr);

  user->dm = *dm;
  PetscFunctionReturn(0);
}
```

Comment: The questin is not about FEM itself at all. A readable FEM implementations are numeros. for example [this](http://fenicsproject.org/documentation/dolfin/1.4.0/cpp/demo/documented/hyperelasticity/cpp/documentation.html). Yet this is the only inside a big library that is positioned as mostly GPU oriented. So it is a question on a specific library understanding PETSc FEM implementation, and not on general FEM.

Comment: @DuckQueen, I removed that portion that described FEM generally now.  I have not had much luck finding out the rest of the answers to your questions.  I am hoping someone else is able to provide you more information.  Good luck in finding a complete answer, Rella is really paying a lot for a good answer!

Answer (score 3):

1) PETSc options are typically set from the command line.  See [PetscOptionsInt()](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Sys/PetscOptionsInt.html), which is the parallel version of PetscOptionsGetInt().  The relevant line of code is:

```
ierr = PetscOptionsInt("-dim", "The topological mesh dimension", "ex52.c", options->dim, &options->dim, NULL);CHKERRQ(ierr);
```

2) The mesh creation function has already been mentioned by Jonathan:

```
PetscErrorCode CreateMesh(MPI_Comm comm, AppCtx *user, DM *dm) { ... }
```

3) In the SNESSetFunction help, you'll be able to see that one is trying to solve `f'(x) x = -f(x)`, where a matrix is formed for both `f'(x)` and `f(x)` (see page 71 of http://acts.nersc.gov/events/Workshop2003/slides/Gropp.pdf). So the forces go into assembly of the matrices for `f'(x)` and `f(x)`.  The relevant part of the code where the equation `f'(x) x = -f(x)` is solved is:

```
ierr = SNESComputeFunction(snes, X, F);CHKERRQ(ierr);
```

4) To see the results from the `SNESComputFunction(ones, X, F);` function call, you may wish to use functions like VecChop() / VecView() as in `src/snes/examples/tutorials/ex12.c`.

Lastly, if you don't expect to have a lot of time on your hands, I strongly suggest that you consider whether the following alternative is possible on GPU--using a higher level package such as MOOSE or FEniCS which directly integrate with PETSc. Making use of a higher level package will save you a considerable amount of time. For example, in FEniCS, one specifies the weak form of the equation rather than assembling the matrix by hand. Another useful thing with FEniCS is that it's possible to specify a spherical mesh. On the following [page](http://fenicsproject.org/documentation/tutorial/prepro.html) in the FEniCS documentation, the relevant line is just `mesh = UnitSphere(10)`.

Comment: I am sorry, I think your answer more deserved the bounty award... You had a very good answer!